# AS3 flash currencyformatter for Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, formatting, numericstepper

I need help in extending the proper string?? to format my numericstepper and/or text display fields to currency formatted. You can download the FLA from [CS5 flash FLA HERE](http://jerodmoore.com/calc5.zip). Thanks

```
 /* start application */
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.globalization.CurrencyFormatter;


//comboBox, I populate values displayed to users

    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "clerical" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "concrete" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "demolition" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "electricians" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "excavation" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "HVAC/Plumbing" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "oil and gas" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "road/bridge construction" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "roofing" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "sewer construction" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "truck driving" } );
    this.comptype.addItem ( { label: "warehousing" } );

this.comptype.addEventListener (Event.CHANGE, selectOrder); 
function selectOrder (event:Event) : void

    {
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "clerical") this.orderTotal.text = ("3.00");
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "concrete") this.orderTotal.text = ("8.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "demolition") this.orderTotal.text = ("10.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "electricians") this.orderTotal.text = ("5.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "excavation") this.orderTotal.text = ("8.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "HVAC/Plumbing") this.orderTotal.text = ("6.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "oil and gas") this.orderTotal.text = ("13.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "road/bridge construction") this.orderTotal.text = ("10.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "roofing") this.orderTotal.text = ("18.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "sewer construction") this.orderTotal.text = ("9.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "truck driving") this.orderTotal.text = ("13.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY
        if (this.comptype.selectedItem.label == "warehousing") this.orderTotal.text = ("7.00"); //make sure my values match the above values EXACTLY

    }
this.outline.calcBtn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, goCalc);
function goCalc (Event:MouseEvent) : void

            {
        this.outline.annualSavings.text = (this.staffrate.value-(14.15 + parseInt(this.orderTotal.text)))*this.payroll.value;
        //this.outline.docCostMonth.text = (this.timesPerDay.value * 260) / 12 * this.docProcCost.value;
        //this.outline.docCostYear.text = (this.outline.docCostMonth.text *12);
        //this.outline.annualSavings.text = ((this.procAutoSaving.value * this.outline.docCostYear.text) / 100);
        }


var cf:CurrencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter( "en_US" );
this.payroll.value = this.payrollOut;
cf.format( this.payrollOut.text );  //??
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey there I hope this helps,

```
myTextField1.text = formatCost(String(4813.134),2,"$",0);// result: $ 4,813.13
```

The function is pretty simple, we call the function `formatCost()`

If you just wish to format it to 0 decimals, `formatCost(value as string,0)`
If you need a currency add that in as the 3rd parameter.
If you need the symbol to appear behind the number, have the position set to 1
So...

```
formatCost(String(8/35*100),1,"%",1);// will give "22.9 %"
```

if wanted, you can tack on more to the formula so that the 5th variable could be the spacer, so that you could change it from a "," to a "." (for french) or as a space " "

```
public function formatCost(v:String, 
           decimal_places:int = 2, 
           currency_symbol:String = "", 
           placement:int = 0){
        v = String(Number(v).toFixed(decimal_places));
        var result:String = new String();
        if(decimal_places == 0){
        }else{
            result = v.substr(-1-decimal_places);
            v = v.substr(0, v.length-1-decimal_places);
        }
        while( v.length > 3 ){
            result = "," + v.substr(-3) + result;
            v = v.substr(0, v.length-3);
        }
        if(v.length > 0){
            if(placement == 0){
                result = currency_symbol + " " + v + result;
            }else if(placement == 1){
                result = v + result + " " + currency_symbol;
            }else{
                result = v + result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }//closes formatCost
```

Answer (score 1):

A better alternative for currency formatting is to use the Adobe class flash.globalization.CurrencyFormatter

```
public static function getDollars(value:Number):String{

        var targetFormatter:CurrencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter("en-US");
        return targetFormatter.format(value, true);

    }
```

This class is very flexible, allowing to you customize the currency appearance for locale.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not paying attention to the variable types.

this.payrollOut -- is a textfield

this.payrollOut.text  -- is the text contained in that textfield

this.payroll.value cannot be assigned a textfield or a text value

So you must convert to the type that it is expecting -- in this case a Number.

```
this.payroll.value = Number(this.payrollOut.text);
```

cf.format is expecting a Number value as well, and will return a String.

an example of usage might be :

```
var payrollAmount:Number = 400;
var payrollCurrencyAmount:String = cf.format(payrollAmount);
```

There are other issues with the code that I see -- payrollOut has no value - so it's still not going to function as expected, but this solves the immediate problem.